# Intent вызывающий фронт камеру для всех возможных Android версий и телефонов

Tags: android, android-intent, камера, android-camera

Столкнулся с проблемой что в сети есть около десятка в меру похожих способов вызвать нативную фронт камеру и практически ни один из них не срабатывает для всех андроид телефонов. Приходилось ли кому-то успешно создавать подобный запрос?(Проверенный на продакшене или серьезном тестирование под многие телефоны)

Для примера добавлю два варианта заведомо не правильные. Не хочу засорять вопрос примерами.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
    } else {
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
    }
```

либо

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 
android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
```

Comment: У меня была похожая проблема. Решение оказалось очень простым. Если поможет и в Вашем случае - то я буду рад.
Вы как intent стартуете?
`startActivity(intent);`?

Попробуйте так: `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose your camera"));`

Comment: была какая-нибуть статистика по твоему решению? Есть подозрения что решение не поможет. Иногда к примеру Intent открывает камеру корректно а камера крешится уже на этапе сохранение фото(Samsung GT-S7262(4.1.2),Google Nexus 6P(8.1),Blu Studio S530(4.4.2)), когда убирали CAMERA_FACING - баг исчезал. То есть способ, как камера была выбрана, не всегда определяющий

Comment: Моё приложение вылетало на некоторых версиях Андроида.
У меня был интент на просмотр файла через галерею, и моё решение помогло мне. Теперь не вылетает